# NetSuite - do users and/or consultants/developers have access to the database?

Tags: netsuite

I am new to Netsuite, and am wondering if there is ever the situation where either the user, or a 3rd party developer/consultant requires direct access to the backend database (where the application data is stored)?

Or is the database, hosted by NetSuite, hidden away from the user, and only accessible via a set of services in front on it?

I come from a background (of other ERP solutions) where consultants and users are quite used to working with the solution at database level (be it reporting off it, adding custom views, tables, stored procedures etc.), so I would like to understand how this works with NetSuite.

Questions are:

1. Does a user/consultant have direct read/write access to the
   database?
2. Can a user/consultant make changes to the database in
   terms of the schema?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For #1, the answer is No, you do not have direct access to DB. You can use the SuiteScript APIs/ SuiteTalk APIs to read/write from the Database.

For #2, You can extend Standard NetSuite Record Types (DB Schema Objects) by defining your own custom fields (Schema Object Attributes), you can also define an entire new custom record with its own custom fields. This can be done through the NetSuite's User Interface.

Answer (score 0):

For #1:
You can sort of get DB access if you pony up for their ODBC access option. I think they call it SuiteAnalytics Connections now. I didn't find it particularly useful overall as it left me with even more questions than I started with.

Answer (score 0):

For #1, the answer is No, you do not have direct access to DB.

You can use the SuiteScript APIs/ SuiteTalk APIs to read/write from the Database but it is very very inefficient,slow and very hard.

There are word limit for your code, it is really very in-effective